# Fundamentals of applications of limits in integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a very fundamental question and a basic question which I am getting very confused while using the calculator and also while solving the question in the paper.

Let me give you an example
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1-\cos2\theta}{2}=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{2}-\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos2\theta}{2}$$
Now when we apply the limit
which is correct
$$=\frac{1*\theta}{2}+\frac{\sin2\theta}{4}$$
In this application should i take the value of $\pi$
as 3.1416.
$$\frac{1*\pi/4}{2}-\frac{1*0}{2}$$
and in the $\cos$ term what should i consider the value of $\pi$
$$\frac{\sin2*\pi/4}{4}-\frac{\sin2*0}{4}$$

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: If the $\pi$ is in the cos term what should i put? and if the $\pi $ is not in the trigonometric function what value should i put Because $\pi$ when used in the trigonometric functions it is taken in radians and outside it is taken as 3.1416. So i am confused.

Comment: Refer to my answer; I do not believe that $\pi$ should ever be approximated in this situation.

Comment: Also make sure to include your differentials in your integrals.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it but i could not produce it with the mathjax script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm not understanding the question; no approximation of $\pi$ should be made. Remember that to evaluate the definite integral
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}d\theta$$
all we have to do is evaluate the indefinite integral of the integrand at the upper bound and subtract off it evaluated at the lower bounds. In this case we know that
$$\int\frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}d\theta=\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{4}+C.$$
This means then that
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}d\theta=\frac{\pi/4}{2}+\frac{\sin(2\pi/4)}{4}-\frac{0}{2}-\frac{\sin(0)}{4}$$
which simplifies to
$$=\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: So the answer is approximately 0.6425.

Comment: @Vinay5forPrime Approximately. If you're using this for an applied situation just go ahead and approximate it, but if you're keeping it in the realm of mathematics I'd avoid approximations like these whenever possible (in most cases).